# Subir archivo via io.socket.request()

Tags: html, nodejs, socket.io, sailsjs

Necesito subir un archivo via io.socket.request(), via formulario y ajax ya lo pude hacer la cabecera del formulario es:

```
<form method="POST" action="/etc" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Pero con **io.socket.request()** no me llega nada a mi formulario, que suelo capturarlo con la funcion siguiente:

```
req.file('file').upload(function(req, res) {...});
```

Este me retorna **undefined**.

Comment: No se puede, yo intenté también y fracasé. Luego leí en un artículo que la comunicación por websocket no soporta transferencia de archivos. Sólo textos.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, cambié a ajax para subirlo. Y me funcionó muy bien.